# Extract Interface from Existing Literal

Tags: typescript

Say I have an object literal as follows:

```
const defaultSettings = {
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  color: 'red'
}
```

Is there any way to easily obtain an interface for that object instead of having to declare one like this by hand?

```
interface Settings {
  height: number,
  width: number,
  color: string
}
```

Comment: What do you plan on doing with that interface?

Comment: If `type Settings = typeof defaultSettings;` does not work for you, you can try to use script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071619/43848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of TypeScript, you can extend type aliases with an interface. So you could get an interface by doing the following:

```
const defaultSettings = {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    color: 'red'
};

type SettingsTypeAlias = typeof defaultSettings;

interface Settings extends SettingsTypeAlias {
}
```

But I don't see the need for that. You might as well just do:

```
type Settings = typeof defaultSettings;
```